# trying to login to a website...getting a bit confused

Tags: android, html, http, authentication

The program below keeps outputing the source code of the original logon page at POINT B. Why is this happening? How can I go about fixing this? want the data of the next webpage that should come up.

```
<form method="POST" name="logonform" action="/check-443/logon.logonform" autocomplete="off">
       <input type="hidden" name="CDT"                  value="12313">
       <input type="hidden" name="NEW_PASSWORD"         value="">
       <tr>
         <td class="content">
           <label for="User">Username</label>
         </td>
         <td>
           <input type="text" name="LOGON" id="id" value="" size="15" maxlength="15">
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="content">
           <label for="pass">Password:</label>
         </td>
         <td>
           <input type="password" name="PASSWORDS" id="pw" value="" size="15">
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <input type="submit" value="Log In">
        </td>
       </form>
```

My code that doesnt seem to work (I saw this online and thought this might be applicable)

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://abc.cba.com");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "Username"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pw", "*****"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Log In", "Log In"));
    try {
        UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
        httppost.setEntity(p_entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        int status_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (status_code >= 300) {
            Log.d("asf", "Error"); //POINT A***************
            return false;

        } else {
            Log.d("asf", EntityUtils.toString(entity)); //POINT B***************
            return true;
        }

    } catch (Exception uee){}
    return false;
```

Comment: @Chris: Thank you cleaning this post. I wasn't sure how to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "login" using your client instead of the HTML login page you need to post your login form data to the same place that the form does.

In this instance you should post to "/check-443/logon.logonform" from your client so as to act like the web form (that's where the current form is posting it's data to).

I suggest going to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and brushing up your understanding on forms.

Comment: I have a dialog that comes up after login.....ughhhhh..how can i even go about making it click that OK. where should i look to find out more about that

Comment: A dialog means you're looking at this in a browser which is using JavaScript opening an `AlertDialog`. If your just retrieving HTML back through the response there won't be a dialog.

Comment: the code when i look at it says this now
<header>..[STUFF].....</SCRIPT></head><!--LOGON logon=success --><body onLoad=reDirect()><BR><BR><BR><BR><CENTER><H1><font color="white">Processing...</h1></CENTER></body></html>
Does this mean a login is a success or do i have to click something to make it go to onLoad?

Comment: It would mean you have to read through and understand the javascript in the reDirect() function then duplicate it in your app. All info you need on Javascript is available at w3schools.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding those hidden input fields (CDT, NEW_PASSWORD) to nameValuePairs and see if that makes any difference. Don't remember if that "Log In" needs to be there or not, might try removing that aswell.

Comment: do i put the field id or name?

Comment: this is kind of what happens stackoverflow.com/questions/8853070/interpreting-http-post-response

Comment: You should use the "name" attribute. You seem to be using "id". Didn't notice that earlier but switch those to "name" aswell.

Comment: I added the cdt number which btw is constantly changing...upon every refresh..... I added a header "/check-443/logon.logonform"  and it now says BAD REQUEST I am a bit confused as to what is going on